# windows store app javascript filesavepicker

Tags: javascript

Struggling to filesavepicker. I want my savepicker to save file, which I open with openpicker and edit them. But when I save, I receive an empty 0 byte file through Savepicker. I am able to save that file with local storage which is automatically saving in my picture folder which i specified. But not with filesavepicker. Please guide me on this how to save image file with filesavepicker.

```
savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert("JPEG file", [".jpg"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using this with my filesavepicker and getting empty 0 byte.
FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync | pickSaveFileAsync method
complete code not added here.

```
fileSavePicker.pickSaveFileAsync().done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

Reason I was getting 0kb byte. Ref msdn bottom.

> **When** the call to this method completes successfully, it returns a storageFile object that was created to represent the saved file. The file name, extension, and location of this storageFile match those specified by the user, **but the file has no content.**
>
> To save the content of the file, your app must write the content to this storageFile.